# Displaying the HTTP protocol within the status bar for a link in Firefox 14.0.1

Tags: firefox, statusbar

So apparently the latest version of Firefox (14.0.1) has introduced a new setting under the guise of "improved usability", but as a web developer I prefer the old functionality.

When I have my mouse hover over a link, the protocol (i.e. `http://`) no longer displays as part of the status bar link. Only the domain and the rest of the URL is displayed (assuming that it isn't also trimmed).

How do I re-enable this functionality? Do I have to [install yet another extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/235283/) to restore the old behaviour?

Comment: I'll point out that as this moment (Aurora build of firefox 15.0a2) it seems only `http://` is trimmed: when I mouseover a `https://` or `ftp://` url, the full url is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` to `false` in `about:config` to change back to the old behaviour. This also restores the location bar to the old behaviour.